# Catching a specific error and re-trying script? - BASH

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which runs a program to migrate some data. This fails around 30-40% of the time.

I want a way to retry the script when this particular error comes up, but I only want to try 3 times before failing.

The script outputs the following when it fails:

```
Error: The connection to the remote server has timed out, no changes      have been committed. (#134 - scope: ajax_verify_connection_to_remote_site)
```

Edit: To be more specific....

```
migration.sh:
#!/bin/bash
various other scripts........
sudo a_broken_migration_program <Variables>
```

I want to retry broken_migration several times, ideally only when it fails with this specific error but if that's too complicated I will settle on retrying all errors.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would suggest that you place your main migration logic into a bash function within your script. The function can return the exit code of the actual migration process and you can create a simple loop with a limit of 3 to retry calling the function.

Comment: "retry .. when this particular error comes up". So you're happy to keep going if other errors appear? Do you know about the shells return code, stored in `$?` it will be 0 if OK, and some non-zero number if there was any kind of error. All good commands should honor this convention. As is, this Q is too board, and many will vote to close. We need to see some code, which makes the problem more specific and testable. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : I want to stop on all errors, except this particular error which is very common. For some reason this migration tool fails quite often, however on 2nd or 3rd run it completes perfectly.

As for being too broad, I don't know how I can be more specific..... 

I have a program being executed from a shell script. I want to catch this specific error and retry. I will update my post to make it clearer....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, just run your command in a loop:

```
#Loop until counter is 3
counter=1
while [[ $counter -le 3 ]] ; do
        yourcommand && break
        ((counter++))
done
```

If `yourcommand` is successful then it will break the loop. If it's unsuccessful then it will increment the counter and loop. Until the counter is 3.

If you just want to retry on a specific error code, you could capture the error on failure, test the code, and increment:

```
#Loop until counter is 3
counter=1
while [[ $counter -le 3 ]]
do
        #command to run
        ssh person@compthatdoesntexist 

        rc=$?
        [[ $rc -eq 255 ]] && ((counter++)) || break
done
```

This example tries to ssh to a box that doesn't exist. We then capture the return code `$?` in variable `$rc`. If `$rc` is `255` ("ssh: Could not resolve hostname compthatdoesntexist: Name or service not known") then it increments the counter and loops. Any other exit code kicks us out of the loop.

Comment: Awesome I think that is exactly what I needed. I tried the first snippet and it works just fine, now I just need to catch the error and find out what the error code is and I should be all set! Hopefully the developer chose to use different codes for different failures. Otherwise I'll have to fail back to your first snippet but I think I can live with retry on all failures if it can't be done. Thanks again.